# Passing dereferenced pointer (ie. by value) to a function expecting a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, dereference, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I was just curious - why does C allow you to pass dereferenced pointers when a function is expecting a pointer. Here's an example:

```
typedef struct {
char message[255];
} Bla;  

// so he's the function that's expecting the pointer
void cool_function(Bla *_bla) {

}

Bla *woot = (Bla *)malloc(2 * sizeof(Bla));

woot[0] = (Bla) {
    .message = "bla bla bla"
};

// woot itself is a pointer, but it's getting dereferenced when I am adding [0]
cool_function(woot[0]);
```

Now that compiles fine, but when I go to actually use _bla (ie. _bla->what), BAM, runtime error.

So this confuses me -- what happens to it if it's passed by value to this function that is clearly expecting a pointer? Why does it even compile?

I'm fairly new to C, so please don't jump all over me. :/

*** UPDATE ***

Sorry for not mentioning earlier, but this is an app for the Pebble Watch, which is using a special version of gcc for specific arm processors (arm-cs-tools).

*** UPDATE 2 ***

I think I found out why it was doing that. The function 'cool_function' was actually in a separate file, and when I declared the function in the header, it was only declared with `void cool_function()` - forgot to include `Bla *_bla`. But the definition was `void cool_function(Bla *_bla)`. It was all my fault for confusing the compiler.

Comment: Please show the definition of woot.  You should be getting a warning of some sorts.

Comment: I added some more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should get the compiler error:

```
error: passing 'Bla' to parameter of incompatible type 'Bla *'; take the address with &
    cool_function(woot[0]);
```

If you use gcc or clang, try to compile your program with -WError and -Wall options.

Comment: This is actually for a Pebble app, and it's using a special version of gcc for specific arm processors (arm-cs-tools). And apologies for not mentioning that earlier.

Comment: it's strange. it must be some kind of lightweight gcc version without type checking.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. Just caught me off-guard, being new to C and all.

Comment: I have to concur with Michal's conclusion.

Comment: I found the issue (stupid mistake by me), and included it in my question.

Answer (score 1):

C will give no compile error because it lacks type checking. In your example it may even not give any runtime error as well, if the values `woot[]` are proper from system point of view

Comment: Since C is statically typed, compilers ***usually* do** type checking on function calls. In this case, the OP is using a pretty liberal compiler.

Comment: Yes, well again depends on compiler. For example TurboC does no typecheck at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
cool_function(&woot[0]);
```

The & operator in this case creates a reference. So you're passing a reference to woot[0]

Note that this means cool_function() can now mutate the contents of woot[0]. If this is undesired, you probably want to do some sort of copy operation.

You could have, for instance, a function that takes a Bla* that copies it into a new instance of Bla* -- this achieving effectively pass-by-value. The trick is you have to do a copy.

Optionally you can make the function take a const Bla* -- that way it shouldn't be able to mutate the values either, technically.

Comment: Thanks Misha, but I already knew that. The question was why it let me compile, and then gave me a runtime error.

Comment: Hm interesting... Sorry if I didn't read into it enough. That assignment to woot[0] is something I actually haven't seen before. I used to do a lot more C back in the day before we had more syntactic sugar like that. Proper GCC gives incompatible type error. Possible compiler bug? Try -Wall and-Werror as @Michal Banasiak suggests. I tend to even use -ansi -pedantic but I'm not sure it'll like that anonymous struct assignment then.

Comment: Also, curious as to the exact runtime error message it gives you. @xil3

Comment: It gives me a very obscure error message, which is specific to the arm-cs-tools (special GCC version for specific ARM processors)

Comment: @MishaNasledov I guess the function wants to treat the passed argument as address, and considering the fact that `bla bla bla` was passed instead, not surprising that it gives a run-time error :)

Comment: This error is what I get when I build your code with the Pebble SDK (See my post below).

Answer (score 1):

I have taken your code and made a full main file from it:

```
#include <pebble.h>

typedef struct {
  char message[255];
} Bla;

// so he's the function that's expecting the pointer
void cool_function(Bla *_bla) {

}

int main() {
  Bla *woot = (Bla *)malloc(2 * sizeof(Bla));

  woot[0] = (Bla) {
      .message = "bla bla bla"
  };

  // woot itself is a pointer, but it's getting dereferenced when I am adding [0]
  cool_function(woot[0]);
}
```

This is what I get when I try to compile it with Pebble SDK 2.0.0:

```
./src/test.c: In function 'main':
../src/test.c:20:3: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'cool_function'
../src/test.c:8:6: note: expected 'struct Bla *' but argument is of type 'Bla'
```

So it looks like comments on your question are all correct. What version of the SDK were you using?

Comment: Note that it does not build because -Werror and -Wall are default options in Pebble SDK.

Comment: Oh man, I think I found out why it was doing that. The function 'cool_function' was actually in a separate file, and when I declared the function in the header, it was only declared with `void cool_function()` - forgot to include `Bla *_bla`. But the definition was `void cool_function(Bla *_bla)`. It was all my fault for confusing the compiler. :(